# Having problems building Cairo on x64 CentOS

Tags: linux, build, 64-bit, centos, cairo

I've done this many times on 32 bit CentOS and everything went ok without a hitch. But now, on x64 CentOS, I can't get cairo to find pixman.

Pixman 0.18.0 is installed in /usr/local/lib (which I believe is the usual location).

Configure for Cairo 1.8.10 can't find it:

```
checking for cairo's image surface backend feature...
checking for pixman... no
no
checking whether cairo's image surface backend feature could be enabled... no (requires pixman-1 >= 0.12.0 http://cairographics.org/releases/)
configure: error: mandatory image surface backend feature could not be enabled
```

I've tried setting environment variable pixman_LIBS=/usr/local/lib but wihtout any luck.

Any idea what is going wrong? Is it possible for me to see where is cairo's configure looking for pixman? Search paths or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/usr/local/lib` is not the usual place. 64-bit libraries are under `lib64` of some sort. Use `file` to verify the libraries under there.

Also, /usr/local is not on most of the paths, so you may need to use `$LIBDIR` as well.

Comment: You were right, I moved pixman libs to /usr/local/lib64 and it works! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible for me to see where is cairo's configure looking for pixman?

Look at `config.log`; for me, I saw lines like this:

```
configure:31597: $PKG_CONFIG --exists --print-errors "$pixman_REQUIRES"
Package pixman-1 was not found in the pkg-config search path.          
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `pixman-1.pc'          
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable                            
No package 'pixman-1' found
```

Which made the problem (and solution) much more obvious than just the output of `./configure`.

To be explicit, I needed to make sure the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` included `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`, since that's where `pixman-1.pc` lived.